# Again I am blocked from asking questions

Tags: discussion

I asked this question after long time of being blocked .

[Is harming others always considered bad?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/59473/is-harming-others-always-considered-bad)

By the way the above Question is not closed or flagged .

But I am blocked again , Is there any ground rules for blocking a user from questions .

If the question is bad just delete it , why block users?

Comment: Please read [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997)

Comment: @AndrewT. if Is harming others always considered bad? was a bad questione , why has it not been deleted or flagged..

Comment: The question block is automatic based on low quality posting history (*all questions*, not only the latest one), and the user is given a chance to post every 6 months and improve the situation. Your latest question, "Is harming others always considered bad" seems getting positive response. Congrats! At least, that's one step to recover from the question ban. The other way is to improve old, closed/deleted questions (if possible).

Comment: @AmruthA: Your deleted questions are counted into the automatic ban, so your best bet is actually editing these and raising a flag that asks for undeleting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the helpful comment of Andrew T. told, you should carefully read the following post:

[What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997)

Here, it is made clear that

1. This is an automatic ban that moderators have nothing to do with.
2. Deleted posts *do count into the algorithm*, i.e. deleting a question does not help

Therefore, you should aim for working over your *existing* (also the deleted!) questions, like e.g.

https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/36157/did-godi-e-who-created-universe-create-math-first-or-universe-first

https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/36152/who-is-the-first-god-to-be-prayed-on-the-earth

https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/47153/will-god-punish-me-if-i-think-vulgar-about-god

https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/45885/what-is-god-doing-now

https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/36894/will-this-idea-end-poverty-on-earth

When you did a major overhaul, you could flag the post and ask for lifting the deletion (and maybe closure) so that the question can receive more positive feedback.

The best way to do this is to **read philosophical texts** and put your interest into the context of existing philosophical texts, e.g. by asking for references that discuss certain diametral views that you think would be relevant.

In other words: Instead of asking what God is doing now, you could ask whether there are any philosophers that discuss God's practical impetus in the current world, i.e. whether there is a position that discusses in which ways He is practical.